# Is there any equivalent function in the opencv gpu namespace to the function cvInvert from the cv namespace?

Tags: opencv, gpu, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to port an openCV application from the cv to the gpu namespace to take advantage of GPU optimizations and I can't find an equivalent function to cvInvert in the docs. Could you please tell me if such a function exists?

Answer (score 0):

Opencv does not have an equivalent GPU invert function.

It would be in the gpu [operations on matrices](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/operations_on_matrices.html#gpu-lut) page but that page does not contain any functions that invert matrices.